# how to display &#247; dynamically in android

Tags: android

how to display the divide ÷ dynamically in textView in android studio instead of setting the text in xml

i tried `textView.setText("&#247;");`

but it displayed `&#247;` instead of ÷

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216620/division-symbol-in-text-file-in-raw-folder

Comment: call `\u00F7` .hope this helps